# How to get the associated store in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Hi I am working with Sencha Touch app, and I have in a one store called "Customers" one model associated, I know when you create a model associated, automatically you create a new store in background, my question is: How to get this store called "templatesStore" (I see the result in the Chrome console) to filter later?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using following syntax:

```
<mainStore>.getAt(0).<assosiationName>();
```

For example,if main store is "Customer" & name given in association as 'Template' then:
Association given in Customer model:

```
   hasMany: [
                {
                    model: 'sample.model.Template',
                    associationKey: 'templates',
                    name: 'templates' // name given here will be accessed from main store
                },

        ]
```

For getting the template store:

```
 Ext.getStore('Customer').getAt(0).templatesStore;
```

or

```
 Ext.getStore('Customer').getAt(0).templates();
```

For filtering 'Customer' store based on template value:

```
  Ext.getStore('Customer').filter([
        { filterFn: function (item) {
         item.templatesStore.filter('templateValue',templateValue); // templateValue contains the value of selected template
         if(item.templatesStore.getCount()>0)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
        }
     }
 ]);
```

Comment: Definetely with your code I am getting the values of the associated store, but my question now is, how to filter parent store based in the filter of the children/associated store?

Comment: Can you explain it more,may be with some simple example

Comment: for example, I have a store with customes, but depending of the customer you can have templates or not.. and in the combo I have different names of templates, I should filter by templates and to get the number of customers shown in the list.